# Laravel populate select field after selecting county input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel 4

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('api/dropdown/cities', function(){
    $county = Input::get('county_id');
    $cities = Place::where('parent_id', $county)->get(array('id','name'));
    return Response::json($cities, 200);
});
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#county_id').change(function(){
        $.getJSON("{{ url('api/dropdown/cities')}}", 
            { option: $(this).val() }, 
            function(data) {
                var model = $('#city_id');
                model.empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    model.append("<option value='"+element.id+"'>" + element.name + "</option>");
                });
            });
    });
});
```

My form:

```
{{ Form::select('county_id', $counties, (isset($data['county_id'])) ? $data['county_id'] : null, array('id' => 'county_id')) }}

<select id="city_id" name="city_id">
    <option>Select a county first</option>
</select>
```

It is almost working, because Laravel Debugbar returns the SQL query:

```
select `id`, `name` from `places` where `parent_id` is null
```

But as you can see, the `parent_id` is NULL, and I can't figure out why the `Input::get('county_id')` is not passed correctly to the route?

Comment: And where do you pass that `county_id` to the route?

Comment: in the getJson : `option: $(this).val()`

Comment: That is probably your problem.  How would `Input::get('county_id')` work if you are sending the parameter with the name of `option`?  Try `Input::get('option');` instead.

Comment: Yep thanks, I just figured out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing

`Input::get('county_id')`

by

`Input::get('option')`